# Does $o(|x-a|^n)$ approximation by a polynomial imply existence of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, taylor-expansion

While reviewing the topic of Taylor expansion, I've noticed that while in all statements about the $n$th order Taylor  polynomial of $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $, it's always assumed that $f\in C^n$, there is no mention of the 'converse'.

So what if all we know about $f$ is that $$f(x)=p(x)+o(|x-a|^n)$$ for some polynomial $p$ of degree $\leq n$.

Is there anything we can say about the existence of $f^{(n)}(a)$?

I assume that no, yet I couldn't think of any counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=|x-a|^{n+1}\mathbf 1_{\mathbb Q}(x)$. Then even the first derivative exists only at $x=a$ (if $n\ge 1$), so there isn't enough of $f$ to even define $f''$ anywhere.